# DefaultMessageListenerContainer concurrentConsumers

Tags: spring-jms

I have a question about DefaultMessageListenerContainer with multiple concurrentConsumers, the container creates differents sessions for each consumer but the problem for me is that the container allow only one message listner instance shared between all consumers, like this i cannot receive many messages and treat them in parallel because each thread will wait for the listener to be available, it is not better to allow each concurrent Consumer to have an exclusive instance of message listener to treat message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is designed for use with thread-safe (stateless) listeners - i.e. no unprotected global state.

It sounds like you use `synchronized` to protect the state, which allows only one listener thread at a time.

If you can't make your listener bean thread-safe, you need to use multiple containers, each with a different listener bean (you can use prototype scope so each container gets its own bean) with concurrency=1.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, ok i understand the design. 
like this if i have 4 concurrent Consumers , the only one instance **(singleton if used with one DMLC )** of the (stateless) listener will be shared between threads and one thread at time will use it to execute its code ( the listener class ) wrapped in its own execution stack while another threads are waiting, even if not sychronized, and i cannot profiting of multi core/processors to execute this listener in parallel, right ? 
especially if i have some long business to execute for each message.

Comment: No, as long as the object is stateless and has no `synchronized` blocks (and specifically the listener method is not marked as `synchronized`), the threads will execute the listener code concurrently.